# Adding elements in the end to a json array of objects in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a json column named "configuration" in an Oracle database with a data like-

```
{"sections":[{"active":true,"code":"page.about"},{"active":true,"code":"page.title"}...]}
```

How can add elements to the "sections" array inside the CLOB?
for example, add this object to the CLOB- {"active":false, "code":"page.body"}

I tried to do this-

```
 UPDATE *TABLE_NAME*
SET configuration = JSON_MODIFY(configuration, 'append $.sections',JSON_QUERY(N'{"active":false,"code":"page.body"}'))
```

but I got this error-
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00917: missing comma
00917. 00000 -  "missing comma"
*Cause:
*Action:

Thanks!

Comment: what version of oracle are you using ?

Comment: 19c version....

Comment: JSON_MODIFY is not a function in Oracle, but in SQL Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION json_append_array(
  json  IN CLOB,
  path  IN VARCHAR2,
  value IN CLOB
) RETURN CLOB
IS
  j_obj JSON_OBJECT_T := JSON_OBJECT_T(json);
  j_arr JSON_ARRAY_T  := j_obj.get_Array(path);
BEGIN
  j_arr.append( JSON_OBJECT_T(value) );
  RETURN j_obj.to_Clob();
END;
/
```

Then you can update the table:

```sql
UPDATE TABLE_NAME
SET configuration = JSON_APPEND_ARRAY(
                      configuration,
                      'sections',
                      '{"active":false,"code":"page.body"}'
                    );
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | CONFIGURATION |
> | --- |
> | {"sections":[{"active":true,"code":"page.about"},{"active":true,"code":"page.title"},{"active":false,"code":"page.body"}]} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=540acec3ba9dd36f4061605f1da123f5)*

Answer (score 1):

You can split the array into rows the use `UNION ALL` to add another row and re-aggregate and use `JSON_MERGEPATCH` to update the object:

```sql
MERGE INTO table_name dst
USING (
  SELECT t.ROWID AS rid,
         a.new_value
  FROM   table_name t
         CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
           SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY 'sections' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(value FORMAT JSON)
                  ) AS new_value
           FROM   (
             SELECT value
             FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                      t.configuration,
                      '$.sections[*]'
                      COLUMNS value CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$'
                    )
             UNION ALL
             SELECT EMPTY_CLOB() || '{"active":false,"code":"page.body"}' FROM DUAL
           )
         ) a
) src
ON (dst.ROWID = src.rid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET configuration = JSON_MERGEPATCH(dst.configuration, src.new_value);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (configuration CLOB CHECK (configuration IS JSON));

INSERT INTO table_name ( configuration )
VALUES ('{"sections":[{"active":true,"code":"page.about"},{"active":true,"code":"page.title"}]}');
```

Then, after the merge statement:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   table_name;
```

Outputs:

> | CONFIGURATION |
> | --- |
> | {"sections":[{"active":true,"code":"page.about"},{"active":true,"code":"page.title"},{"active":false,"code":"page.body"}]} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d12548636d79107162a89cc79c34dd1b)*